# Find occurance of word in sentence

Tags: c, string

I have made program where you input sentence and then words. If the word from sentence is in words you inputed it mark the work in setnence. Example:

```
input sentence

My name is John.

input words
name
Why
do
apple

Final output

My [name] is John.
```

This works. I split word on tokens (by " ") using strtok and add them into structure. I store inputed words in an array. But the problem is, when user input
" name" ( with whitespace at start) it does not match the word in sentence, because i split it with " " which means there are not whitespaces in structure.

Is there any way ,without bruteforce looping to check i the word exist in sentence with whitespace? Example

```
Input sentence
My name is john

words
 name
is
Final output
My[ name] [is] John.
```

Comment: `fgets()` and `strstr()`?

Comment: You should provide some code, we can't know why your code isn't working if you don't provide any.

Comment: wouldnt strstr() result in unwanted behaviout where in sentence
"Hello my name is John" , the word "Joh" , would find a match in word John? I think op wants match whole words, not just substring of the words.

Answer (score 2):

You need to strip out all punctuation and whitespace from your tokens. If you have 'John' in your input set you will find you do not match against "John." from the original sentence.

What I recommend is that when you get to a word, you trim it (.trim()) and then remove any unwanted characters (",", "-", ".").

You may also want to consider whether or not the program is case sensitive.

Comment: well if there were two spaces before name, say "  name",  this would still match even if there were only one space in the sentence. I'm not sure whether OP intends this or not. It depends entirely on what OP defines "word" as. If its just a bunch of characters(including whitespace) then he cannot tokenize it.